# What's a good word to mean being sorry for making lots of requests?

Tags: single-word-requests

I checked on my intern multiple times in the last days.  I said "why this still has not been worked on ..." in different ways many times. So many that I felt I was being a little XXX?  What should that XXX word be?  "demanding" is NOT exactly right. I felt I should not leave the intern so little "room" by constantly asking for status update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sorry for being such a nudnik."

Oxford Dictionaries

North American informal

Nudnik:  A pestering, nagging, or irritating person; a bore.

Answer (score 0):

***[Insistent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/insistent)*** may convey the idea you want to express:

> - earnest or emphatic in dwelling upon, maintaining, or demanding something; persistent; pertinacious.

Dictionary.com